# AJAX Jquery call not returning response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, ros

Hi I am running an AJAX call to a Flask server using Jquery but it is not returning success response message once i run :

```
os.system("roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch map_file:=$HOME/maps/"+mapname+".yaml")
```

Here is the request I am making:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/test', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: new_freq,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }       
})
```

flask server code,

```
    @app.route("/test" , methods=['POST'])
    def test():
        mapname = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        os.system("roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch map_file:=$HOME/maps/"+mapname+".yaml")
   
        return(mapname)
```

anybody knows how to return the AJAX success response?

EDIT:i have replaced the command inside `os.system()` with `ifconfig` and `mkdir` it all works and got the success response.This command `roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch map_file:=$HOME/maps/mapname.yaml` initiate a node and never run out.So is there a way i could return the success response even the node is running?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Like you said, `turtlebot3_navigation.launch` will run until terminated. Do you just want to start it? I.e., would you like a success response already on start? Then you should just run it in the background.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, it works.Is there any way to return the AJAX response once the map load is completed(even the map load is completed the above launch file will run the node in the background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the sense that you just want to start the launch file, but not wait until it is terminated. If that's the case then you want to start the `roslaunch` command in the background, i.e., detach it from your running python process:

```py
import subprocess

@app.route("/test" , methods=['POST'])
def test():
    mapname = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    subprocess.Popen(["roslaunch", "turtlebot3_navigation", "turtlebot3_navigation.launch", "map_file:=$HOME/maps/"+mapname+".yaml"])
    return(mapname)
```

Comment: Glad it works. Please don't forget to upvote + accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I don't have enough enough reputation to upvote right now.Once i do i definitely will do that.Guys seeing this give this man some upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your success function is in the wrong position, try this.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/test', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: new_freq
  },
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
    
})
```

Comment: It not in the wrong position. Your answer `success` is in the wrong position and will not work at all now. Please review your answer.